# wordpress navigation/ menu doesn't add current-item

Tags: php, css, wordpress, nav

I think I've done everything correctly. I registered the menus.

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu' ),
    'secondary' => __( 'Secondary Menu' ),
    'third' => __( 'Third - Contacts' )
) );
```

And echoed it in my theme.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary') ); ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'secondary') ); ?>
```

While this works, it doesn't add a class `.active` or `.current-item`. As far as I know, it should do that by default.

Btw. I cannot probably use `menu` instead of `theme_location` since I'm using wplang and the menus are different in different languages.

Thanks.

Comment: So you mean your menus are missing CSS , right?

Comment: No, in the HTML it doesn't add class for current item

Comment: I mean to say your issue is wordpress class style for menu is not applying automatically , right?

Comment: yes, thats wha I mean

Comment: is  that ready made theme or you have converted html to wordpress?

Comment: you can apply class to menu by adding `'container_class' => 'my_extra_menu_class'` to `wp_nav_menu`

Comment: i want to add class to the CURRENT ITEM not to a menu container...

Comment: Can you please share website URL? to check in detail.

Comment: ok are you talking about top menu? where active class it not applying. News , About us?